# HMVC Unable to load the requested file

Tags: codeigniter-2, hmvc

Hello i have some problem, i use Codeigniter Modular Extensions - HMVC.

Problem is when i try to show my module.

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested file: quicklinks_show.php

I have two modules

1.Dashboard
2.Quicklinks

The problem arises when I try to call and show another module in dashboard module.
I put this code in Dashboard/view/dashboard_view.php module

```
<div id="modules">
   <?php modules::run('quicklinks/show');?>
</div>
```

In my Quicklinks modules i have simple Show() function

```
public function show(){
     $this->load->view('quicklinks_show');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the view folder is named correct, so controller**s**, model**s** and view**s**

Answer (score 0):

Try this pull request:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1818

I tested that and it looks like this is the best hmvc solution.

Download here: https://github.com/dchill42/CodeIgniter/tree/hmvc_unit

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late to reply but you may get the answer in this [in-depth article of HMVC](http://fearlessdeveloper.com/hmvc-pattern1/).